# NullPointerException CustomList ViewAdapter with base adapter Android

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, baseadapter

I am trying to create a custom listview with one image and 3 textViews, but I am getting this NullPointException error a the line "listView.setAdapter(adapter);" of my code. 
By debugging the app, I could see that my List produtos is getting all the necessary data from my SQLite database, so I do not believe the issue is there. I am setting a fix image by now, because this was my first test with customs listviews. So I was trying to make this works first, then I will implement the rest.

`    My activity which should implement the custom listview--

```
 public class ShowAllProdutosActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 ListView listView;
 ArrayList<Produto> produtos;
 String[] titleArray;
 String[] descriptionArray;
 String[] priceArray;
 int[] imagensArray;
 CustomListViewAdapter adapter;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // TODO: Implement this method
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.listview_procura); /*Fixed*/
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     produtos = new ArrayList<>();
     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaProdutos);
     final DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
     produtos = db.getAllProdutos();
     db.closeDB();
     if (!produtos.isEmpty()) {
         adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,produtos);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
     } else {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Nenhum Produto Encontrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
     }
  }
}`
```

`    CustomListViewAdapter.java--

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;

protected List<Produto> listProds;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Produto> listProds) {
    this.listProds = listProds;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public int getCount() {
    return listProds.size();
}

public Produto getItem(int position) {
    return listProds.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return listProds.get(position).getId();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        row = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item,
                parent, false);

        holder.txtName = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.txtViewNomeProduto);
        holder.txtDesc = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.txtViewDescricaoProduto);
        holder.txtPrice = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.txtViewPrecoProduto);
        holder.imgProd = (ImageView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.produtoImgView);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Produto prod = listProds.get(position);
    holder.txtName.setText(prod.getProd_name());
    holder.txtDesc.setText(prod.getProd_desc());
    holder.txtPrice.setText(prod.getProd_price() + " R$");
    holder.imgProd.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtDesc;
    TextView txtPrice;
    ImageView imgProd;
}
```

My activity layout listview_procura.xml--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listaProdutos"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

My item layout listview_item.xml--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/produtoImgView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/txtViewNomeProduto"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/produtoImgView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/produtoImgView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/txtViewDescricaoProduto"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/produtoImgView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewNomeProduto"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtViewPrecoProduto"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtViewPrecoProduto"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txtViewPrecoProduto" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/txtViewPrecoProduto"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/produtoImgView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And the log I am getting--

```
04-12 20:36:30.533  28463-28463/com.paum.pechinchamercado E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.paum.pechinchamercado, PID: 28463
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.paum.pechinchamercado/com.paum.pechinchamercado.activities.ShowAllProdutosActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.paum.pechinchamercado.activities.ShowAllProdutosActivity.onCreate(ShowAllProdutosActivity.java:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)      
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`

Comment: add an exception handler in your getView method to catch any exceptions there, put a break point at the catch(Exception e) area and see if an exception is occurring.

Comment: There is a problem with wrong layout selection.

Comment: Piyush Gupta, you were right, I already fixed, but now it is not presenting anything. fljabour I set a try catch and debug it with the break point int the catch(Exception), although it did not pass through it at running time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting your content view to `R.layout.add_prod` but you claim the layout is called `listview_procura.xml`.  If you are setting the content view to the wrong layout then calling `findViewById()` to get the `ListView` will return null if you don't have a `ListView` with that same id in `add_prod.xml`

Comment: I can't believe I have made that mistake. Thanks for point out, I guess I was too blind for the time I spent trying it. Now, it is just not presenting anything in the listview and it is another issue hahaha

Comment: we all need a second pair of eyes sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the issue with the layout which kris larson point it out, the problem I was facing that did not display the list view was at line "return convertView" should be instead "return row"